# Schedule Adherence for Work force management

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on generating a Workforce management schedule adherence report using SQL.

I have 2 SQL tables: `dbo.Scheduled_Shifts`, and `dbo.Actual_Work`

Here is the sample data from both tables.

`dbo.Scheduled_Shifts`

```
EmpID     ScheduleType           StartTime                    EndTime
  1           Work         2018-03-01 09:00:00.000     2018-03-01 11:00:00.000
  1           Break        2018-03-01 11:00:00.000     2018-03-01 11:15:00.000
  1           Work         2018-03-01 11:15:00.000     2018-03-01 13:00:00.000
  1           Lunch        2018-03-01 13:00:00.000     2018-03-01 14:00:00.000
  1           Work         2018-03-01 14:00:00.000     2018-03-01 16:00:00.000
```

`dbo.Actual_Work`

```
EmpID     ActualWorkType           StartTime                    EndTime
  1           Work         2018-03-01 09:10:00.000     2018-03-01 10:00:00.000
  1           Fax          2018-03-01 10:00:00.000     2018-03-01 10:02:00.000
  1           Work         2018-03-01 10:02:00.000     2018-03-01 11:10:00.000
  1           Break        2018-03-01 11:10:00.000     2018-03-01 11:20:00.000
  1           Work         2018-03-01 11:20:00.000     2018-03-01 13:00:00.000
  1           Lunch        2018-03-01 13:00:00.000     2018-03-01 13:55:00.000
  1           Work         2018-03-01 13:55:00.000     2018-03-01 16:05:00.000
```

From these tables, I want to achieve if the employee followed (or stick) to the schedule.

Here is the dataset I am expecting to acheive:

```
EmpId    ActualWorkType       AW_StartTime                AW_EndTime            ScheduleType             Schd_StartTime             Schd_EndTime
  1          Work         2018-03-01 09:10:00.000    2018-03-01 10:00:00.000         Work           2018-03-01 09:00:00.000     2018-03-01 10:00:00.000
  1          Fax          2018-03-01 10:00:00.000    2018-03-01 10:02:00.000         Work           2018-03-01 10:00:00.000     2018-03-01 10:02:00.000
  1          Work         2018-03-01 10:02:00.000    2018-03-01 11:10:00.000         Work           2018-03-01 10:02:00.000     2018-03-01 11:00:00.000
  1          Break        2018-03-01 11:10:00.000    2018-03-01 11:20:00.000         Break          2018-03-01 11:00:00.000     2018-03-01 11:15:00.000
  1          Work         2018-03-01 11:20:00.000    2018-03-01 13:00:00.000         Work           2018-03-01 11:15:00.000     2018-03-01 13:00:00.000
  1          Lunch        2018-03-01 13:00:00.000    2018-03-01 13:55:00.000         Lunch          2018-03-01 13:00:00.000     2018-03-01 14:00:00.000
  1          Work         2018-03-01 13:55:00.000    2018-03-01 16:05:00.000         Work           2018-03-01 14:00:00.000     2018-03-01 16:00:00.000
```

I would appreciate algorithm, or psuedo-code or SQL query to solve it.

EDIT:
Adding query to generate table and sample data

```
create table #Scheduled_Shifts
(
    EmpId int,
    ScheduleType varchar(50),
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime
)

insert into #Scheduled_Shifts values
(1, 'Work', '2018-03-01 09:00:00.000','2018-03-01 11:00:00.000'),
(1, 'Break', '2018-03-01 11:00:00.000', '2018-03-01 11:15:00.000'),
(1, 'Work', '2018-03-01 11:15:00.000', '2018-03-01 13:00:00.000'),
(1, 'Lunch', '2018-03-01 13:00:00.000', '2018-03-01 14:00:00.000'),
(1, 'Work', '2018-03-01 14:00:00.000', '2018-03-01 16:00:00.000')


create table #Actual_Work
(
    EmpId int,
    ActualWorkType varchar(50),
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime
)

insert into #Actual_Work values
 (1,'Work','2018-03-01 09:10:00.000','2018-03-01 10:00:00.000'),
 (1,'Fax', '2018-03-01 10:00:00.000','2018-03-01 10:02:00.000'),
 (1,'Work','2018-03-01 10:02:00.000','2018-03-01 11:10:00.000'),
 (1,'Break','2018-03-01 11:10:00.000','2018-03-01 11:20:00.000'),
 (1,'Work','2018-03-01 11:20:00.000','2018-03-01 13:00:00.000'),
 (1,'Lunch','2018-03-01 13:00:00.000','2018-03-01 13:55:00.000'),
 (1,'Work','2018-03-01 13:55:00.000','2018-03-01 16:05:00.000')
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It suggests things like showing the results you seek, showing the work you've done, ... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply split each of the activities performed by worker against the start and end time of the expected activity schedule. Then you can determine within each segment whether the actual activity performed matches the scheduled activity. This method will not give you the exact same result set you have posted (you will have more rows) but it will give you a better reflection of the how well a worker is adhering to the schedule. The following query gives an example of how this can be done:

```
;WITH CTE_ActualWorkBySchedule
AS
(
    SELECT       A.EmpId
                ,A.ActualWorkType 
                ,A.StartTime AS AW_StartTime
                ,A.EndTime AS AW_EndTime
                ,S.ScheduleType
                ,S.StartTime AS Schd_StartTime
                ,S.EndTime AS Schd_EndTime
                ,(
                    CASE
                        WHEN A.StartTime < S.StartTime THEN S.StartTime
                        ELSE A.StartTime
                    END
                 ) AS AW_StartTimeClipped
                ,(
                    CASE
                        WHEN A.EndTime > S.EndTime THEN S.EndTime
                        ELSE A.EndTime
                    END
                 ) AS AW_EndTimeClipped
    FROM        [dbo].[Actual_Work] A
    INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Scheduled_Shifts] S ON S.EmpId = A.EmpId AND S.StartTime < A.EndTime AND S.EndTime > A.StartTime
),
AdherenceToScheduleDuration
AS
(
    SELECT   WS.EmpId
            ,WS.ActualWorkType
            ,WS.AW_StartTime
            ,WS.AW_EndTime
            ,WS.ScheduleType
            ,WS.Schd_StartTime
            ,WS.Schd_EndTime
            ,WS.AW_StartTimeClipped
            ,WS.AW_EndTimeClipped
            ,(
                CASE
                    WHEN WS.ActualWorkType = WS.ScheduleType THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, AW_StartTimeClipped, AW_EndTimeClipped)
                    ELSE 0
                END
             ) AS DurationWithinSchedule
    FROM    CTE_ActualWorkBySchedule WS
)
SELECT  *
FROM    AdherenceToScheduleDuration SD
```

You can take this method on step further and now calculate how well the worker adheres to schedule as a % of time that activity performed matches the scheduled activities as follow:

```
;WITH CTE_ActualWorkBySchedule
AS
(
    SELECT       A.EmpId
                ,A.ActualWorkType 
                ,A.StartTime AS AW_StartTime
                ,A.EndTime AS AW_EndTime
                ,S.ScheduleType
                ,S.StartTime AS Schd_StartTime
                ,S.EndTime AS Schd_EndTime
                ,(
                    CASE
                        WHEN A.StartTime < S.StartTime THEN S.StartTime
                        ELSE A.StartTime
                    END
                 ) AS AW_StartTimeClipped
                ,(
                    CASE
                        WHEN A.EndTime > S.EndTime THEN S.EndTime
                        ELSE A.EndTime
                    END
                 ) AS AW_EndTimeClipped
    FROM        [dbo].[Actual_Work] A
    INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Scheduled_Shifts] S ON S.EmpId = A.EmpId AND S.StartTime < A.EndTime AND S.EndTime > A.StartTime
),
AdherenceToScheduleDuration
AS
(
    SELECT   WS.EmpId
            ,WS.ActualWorkType
            ,WS.AW_StartTime
            ,WS.AW_EndTime
            ,WS.ScheduleType
            ,WS.Schd_StartTime
            ,WS.Schd_EndTime
            ,WS.AW_StartTimeClipped
            ,WS.AW_EndTimeClipped
            ,(
                CASE
                    WHEN WS.ActualWorkType = WS.ScheduleType THEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, AW_StartTimeClipped, AW_EndTimeClipped)
                    ELSE 0
                END
             ) AS DurationWithinSchedule
    FROM    CTE_ActualWorkBySchedule WS
)
SELECT  SD.EmpId
        ,CAST(SUM(DurationWithinSchedule) AS FLOAT) / CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, MIN(SD.Schd_StartTime), MAX(SD.Schd_EndTime)) AS FLOAT) * 100 AS AdherenceToSchedulePercentage
FROM    AdherenceToScheduleDuration SD
GROUP BY SD.EmpId
```